# Hide Follow button Twitter Card Blockquote

Tags: button, twitter, hide

I need to hide the follow button on Twitter card using :

```
<blockquote width="581" height="250" class="twitter-tweet"><p></p><a href="https://twitter.com/twitterapi/status/'+tt[i][1]+'" data-datetime="2011-11-07T20:21:07+00:00"></a></blockquote></div>
```

How do you hide the follow button on a card ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The twitter widget expands into an iframe, so you would have to wait until it is fully loaded. Afterwards you could either fully remove the button or hide it. You will need a little JavaScript. The problem is that you would have to wait until it is loaded. I don't know how to catch when the tweet is fully loaded so I will be checking for the button every 100 milliseconds until it appears. You could of course change that to fit your needs.

JS:

```
window.setTimeout(removeButton, 100);

function removeButton() {
    var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe.twitter-tweet');
    if(iframe == undefined) {
        window.setTimeout(removeButton, 100);
        return;
    }
    var button = iframe.contentDocument.querySelector('.follow-button.profile');
    if(button == undefined) {
        window.setTimeout(removeButton, 100);
        return;
    }

    //Hide
    button.style.display = 'none';

    //Or remove
    button.parentNode.removeChild(button); //Note: Not using button.remove() because of compatibility
}
```

This of course right now only works for one single tweet. If you wanted to remove multiple Follow buttons, you would have to modify this script a little bit.